# When is there a newer version of Samba 4?

Tags: samba4

Can someone tell me when Ubuntu comes with a newer version of there samba 4 package. The current version is samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu.

When I look at the Samba site, this version is EOL, and already as of 2017-03-11.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on ?

Comment: I'm on 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 4):

You are on 14.04 or 16.04 (both use 4.3.11). Those 2 will never receive a newer version; they will only get patched (that means it gets updated but the version number will never change) if there is a security issue.

You have at least 2 options to get a newer version:

1. 17.10 uses 4.6.7; 18.04 will use 4.7.3
2. You can use the [samba team nightly](https://launchpad.net/~samba-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to install the newest version.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:samba-team/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   to add the PPA.

Comment: Sorry for this delayed answer. Thanks for your answer, but I tried to add the repository, but alas, it failed ("The repository doesn't have a Release file"). I keep finding it strange that that an LTS version, doesn't keep up with the versions of Samba4, and stays stuck with an EOL version. (Even no security fixes anymore) https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_Release_Planning#Current_Stable_Release

Comment: I now have a tough decision to make. Do I go for the old version, or do I compile myself the samba4.org version. Do I go for easy but insecure, or more maintenance and secure?

Comment: "Do I go for easy but insecure" What do you mean by that? SECURITY patches are applied to all Ubuntu packages that are active. That includes samba. But that does NOT mean you get complete new versions in older Ubuntu. I don't see a problem?!

Comment: **LTSupport** does not mean **up to date** (regarding new versions/features): security fixes are back-ported for sure! -- this isn't strange but reasonable... so you just have to setup your service once based on an LTS-version and have no fear, that a sh...iny new version/feature may break your setup.

Comment: Hi Rinzwind, DJCrshdummy, I believe you when you say there are security patches applied, but, for me to understand, who is making them? The samba4 doesn't supply them since 2017-03-17.
And I know LTS is not always the latest and greatest, but I thought that at least the versions would be, when EOL, be updated, especially when an LTS is running for 5 years.

Comment: November 21st: https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3486-1/ December 15th: https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-2619.html and here is a list http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/pkg/samba4.html

Comment: The Samba Team Nightly PPA is currently **deprecated**. Trusty (14) and Xenial (16) users should instead use [The Linux Schools Project](https://launchpad.net/~linux-schools/+archive/ubuntu/samba-latest) PPA, i.e. run the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linux-schools/samba-latest ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y` in order to add such PPA to the system, update the system's APT cache of repositories and then upgrade Samba 3.X to Samba 4.7.12.